# System.Management error in UWP

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10

I am writing an app to read current screen brightness and set it pragmatically. After doing some search, I found the following code which requires **System.Management** dll

```
static byte GetBrightness()
        {
            ManagementScope s = new ManagementScope("root\\WMI");
            SelectQuery q = new SelectQuery("WmiMonitorBrightness");

            ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher(s, q);

            ManagementObjectCollection moc = mosGet();

            byte curBrightness = 0;

            foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject o in moc)
            {
                curBrightness = (byte)o.GetPropertyValue("CurrentBrightness");
                break; 
            }

            moc.Dispose();
            mos.Dispose();

            return curBrightness;
        }

static void SetBrightness(byte targetBrightness)
        {
           ManagementScope s = new ManagementScope("root\\WMI");

            SelectQuery q = new SelectQuery("WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods");

            ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher(s, q);

            ManagementObjectCollection moc = mos.Get();

            foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject o in moc)
            {
                o.InvokeMethod("WmiSetBrightness", new Object[] { UInt32.MaxValue, targetBrightness }); 
            }

            moc.Dispose();
            mos.Dispose();
        }
```

I was able to add **System.Management** dll in UWP. But when I build, I get the following errors :

**C# Reference to type 'Component' claims it is defined in 'System', but it could not be found**

Is there any way to achieve this in UWP?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use [System.Management Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management(v=vs.110).aspx) which is awailable only for .Net applications.
You can't use this dll with UWP application

Comment: any alternate solution for such purpose in UWP?